# How to inspect element while emulating touch screen in Chrome DevTools?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, emulation, google-chrome-devtools

I need to right click on an element and go to inspect element.

I have tried to right click but since its a touch device emulator that action doesn't make sense, the dropdown doesn't appear.

It works fine when i am not in the emulator mode checking for things, but when i am in the emulator for touch devices (ipad, iphone, galaxy), I lose the right click.
How do it make chrome open that html tag just like the inspect element, so i don't have to dig through the html trying to find the element i want?

thanks in advance! :)

Comment: thank you the magnifying glass helped... since i still need the touch things to work...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Left click and hold on the element in the emulation window.

The context menu will then appear, and you'll need to move your mouse to `Inspect Element` before releasing the click to activate it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use either the magnifying glass in the top left corner of the developer tools, or you could turn off the touch sensor emulation by going to Emulation|Sensors|Emulate touch screen and turn it back on after you find your element.

Comment: Is there a reason why this is downvoted? It contains two out of the three ways to inspect element with touch enabled.

Comment: I agree. This is the methodology I use on a regular basis. This definitely is a valid answer...

Comment: this is a valid answer i agree... however its easier to just long click on the element....

Comment: I guess I just mean it is a "quality" answer per my understanding of the [guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Its a successful "attempt to answer the question", works for those who wish to use it, and its not spam, offensive, abusive, or hate speech. Whether its easier is subjective to each individual. I just don't understand the down-vote.

Comment: @Dmjo I agree that you should not have downvoted quantumwannabe's answer. It was well researched and correct, and answered the question. According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), you should upvote any answers meeting that criteria, and (optionally) mark the one that best worked for *you* as accepted (check mark).